# How to run a .m (matlab) file through java and matlab control?

Tags: java, matlab, execution

I have 2 .m files. One is the function and the other one (read.m) reads then function and exports the results into an excel file. I have a java program that makes some changes to the .m files. After the changes I want to automate the execution/running of the .m files. I have downloaded the matlabcontrol.jar and I am looking for a way to use it to invoke and run the read.m file that then reads the function.
Can anyone help me with the code? Thanks

I have tried this code but it does not work.

```
public static void tomatlab() throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException {


        MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options =
            new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
                .build();
        MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
        MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();


        proxy.eval("addpath('C:\\path_to_read.m')");
        proxy.feval("read");
        proxy.eval("rmpath('C:\\path_to_read.m')");

        // close connection
        proxy.disconnect();

    }
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what "does not work"?

Comment: @bdecaf It wont run the read.m file properly. It creates the output (excel file) in random destination folders.

Comment: sounds to me like the Java part is fine but read.m needs debugging. Can you post a simple version that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the official tutorial in the Wiki of the project](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough), it seems quite straightforward to start with this API.

The path-manipulation might be a bit tricky, but I would give a try to loading the whole script into a string and passing it to `eval` (*please note I have no prior experience with this specific Matlab library*). That could be done quite easily (with joining `Files.readAllLines()` for example).

Hope that helps something.

Comment: Do I need to pass the whole script to eval? Isnt there a method to just execute a .m file?

Comment: As I stated, I don't know the API, but after browsing the Javadocs, I haven't found any way to do that. Probably there is a function for that, although the workaround I wrote may work for you. Maybe you should ask around the project's discussion list.